# Problem with properly using/building IOS Framework

Tags: ios, cocoapods, ios-frameworks

I'm building my own IOS framework for some purpose, and later created a `cocoapod` [cocoapod link](https://cocoapods.org/pods/AppCarry) as well.

When I'm using this inside a project, I was able to build the project perfectly but when I try to upload the archived app to `appstoreconnect`, it shows my framework as a separate entity inside the app archive.

[image]

One thing to add as well **I'm using this framework as a pod in the project**.

**Why this is bothering me?** I'm using other frameworks in the app like `Google Framework`, `Firebase Framework` but they don't show up like this.

Can any one explain why it's showing like this? and do I need a separate `Apple Developer` account to create my own framework?

Please forgive me if this issue is so beginner, I'm a beginner as well and couldn't find it online.

Thanks

Comment: The Firebase frameworks are linked statically and linked into the app at build time. Dynamic frameworks are packaged separately and linked at load time.

Comment: Adding to above comment and your question. No you don't need to create a separate Apple Developer account to create your own framework.